# Getting a name error when seeding a database in ruby on rails. How do I include app context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, seed

I have a seed script called load.rb in the db directory of an application.  I just got this app from a client so not sure how to run this script.  I get a name error on all of the Model.create(...) statements.  I guess this is because the Rails environment is not loaded.

There is no indication that this load script was run via a rake task because I see no custom rake tasks in the app.  Is this a "Rails thing"? ...in other words, is there a command I am not aware of that will load the app context and execute load.rb in the db directory?

If not, how can load the app context in the file so that I can simply type "ruby load.rb" to load the database?

The file is literally just a bunch of create statements:

```
Quiz.create(:name=> "1")
Quiz.create(:name=> "2")
Quiz.create(:name=> "3")
Quiz.create(:name=> "4")
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post the script, or least the important looking parts?

Comment: the file is a bunch of create statements, see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's probably just being run from the console.  For development, you'd simply start with

```
./script/console
```

from your Rails root directory.

Then inside your console, load the script.

```
>> load "db/load.rb"
```

Comment: i still get db/load.rb:2: uninitialized constant Quiz (NameError)

Comment: Have you set up your database.yml file and run your database migrations yet?

rake db:migrate